# Accessing Apache Web Server on Ubuntu from a Windows Machine on the LAN

Tags: windows, apache, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I recently set up an Apache web server on my Ubuntu 18.04 Machine.  Right now, I only use it to view html files on my local machine.  I attempted to access the server from a Windows machine that is connected to the same network, but I keep getting a "Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND".  I'm able to access the web server from the local machine just fine.

Additionally, I want to use this web server to test ARP spoofing and DNS spoofing.  Not being able to connect to the website from other machines is prohibiting me from doing so.

Comment: A few questions to try to narrow down the problem...

1) on which interface / address the apache is listening to?
2) are the firewall ports open (probably 80, 8080 or 443)?
3) are you try to access the server via IP address oder hostname (e.g. http://192.168.1.12 vs http://myhost.lan)?

Comment: I'm using wlan0.  And Apache is listening on port 80, which is the default if I'm not mistaken.  And yes, I'm trying to access the server via IP on a Windows machine.